# Problems with Linked List of String in C

Tags: c, string, linked-list

I'm trying to make a minishell and store all the commands the user types, and when the user enters `history` it should display all the commands the user has typed so far, and when the user types `history -c` then it should clear the linked list.

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char* data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *create_node(char* data)
{
    node *ptr = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Out of memory in create_node()\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    ptr->data = data;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    return ptr;
}

node *insert_node(node *head, char* data)
{
    node *temp;
    if (head == NULL)
        return create_node(data);
    temp = head;
    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {     
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    // 'temp' is pointing to the last node in the list now.
    temp->next = create_node(data);
    return head;
}

void print_list(node *head)
{
    node *temp;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("(empty list)\n");
        return;
    }

    for (temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next)
        printf("%s%c", (char*)temp->data, '\n');
}

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    char buf[1024];
    char * args[MAX_ARGS];
    char ** arg;
    node *head = NULL;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("#");
        if (fgets (buf, 1024, stdin ))
        {
            head = insert_node(head, buf);
            arg = args;
            *arg++ = strtok(buf, SEPARATORS);  // tokenize input
            while ((*arg++ = strtok(NULL, SEPARATORS)));
            if (args[0])
            {
                //#byebye command, exist the while loop.
                if (!strcmp(args[0], "byebye")) {
                    break;
                }      
  
                if (!strcmp(args[0], "history"))
                {
                    // command history with flag c

                    if (args[1] && !strcmp(args[1], "-c"))
                    {
                        // clear the linked list
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        print_list(head);
                        printf("\n");
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                arg = args;
                while (*arg) fprintf(stdout, "%s ", *arg++);
                fputs ("\n", stdout);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But this is my output:

```
#hello

hello

#adding

adding

#to list

to list

#history

history

history

history

history
```

So, instead of printing out all the commands, it prints out `history` and I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please help, it has been awhile since I touched C and pointers.

Comment: `ptr->data = malloc(sizeof(char*)); ptr->data = (char*)data;` is a bit strange. That is a very small allocation, and, if you are you trying to copy a string, that just overwrites the pointer to the memory just allocated. The code is very hard to read though: far too much whitespace.

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code?

Comment: all your doing is moving pointers around.  you're not copying anything. in `create_node` you just assign *data to the `node->data`.  you made no copy

Comment: @jiveturkey, I don't understand how I'm making no copy? I allocated memory for the node and assigned the string to `ptr->data = data`.

Comment: You probably want to learn about `strcpy`. Why do you think this function is needed?

Comment: Look at `create_node`.  You allocate a new node BUT you assign the data pointer passed in to the data pointer in the node.  There is no character copy.  Look at how @Remy Lebeau did it

Comment: Yes I did @Quimby, it seems to work fine because i used the print statement to see what' string is getting stored and it seems to work fine until I input history and suddenly all the linked lists have history as the data instead of the original data

Comment: There are a few linked list libraries already debugged. GitHub has a bunch.

Answer (score 3):

Your `create_node()` is implemented wrong.

You are leaking the memory you `malloc()` for the `node::data` member, as you are immediately re-assigning the `node::data` to point at the same memory that the input `char*` parameter is pointing at, thus losing the `malloc`'ed memory.

As such, all of your created nodes end up pointing at the same `char[]` buffer in `main()`, which is being reused for every string the user types in.

`create_node()` needs to make a *copy* of the `char` data, which is probably what you *intended* to do, but didn't do so correctly.  Try this:

```c
node *create_node(char* data)
{
    node *ptr = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Out of memory in create_node()\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    ptr->data = strdup(data);
    ptr->next = NULL;

    if (ptr->data == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Out of memory in create_node()\n");
        free(ptr);
        exit(1);
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

And then you need to add a new function to free each node and its `data` when you are done using it, eg:

```c
node* free_node(node* n)
{
    node *next = n->next;
    free(n->data);
    free(n);
    return next;
}

...

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    node *head = NULL;
    ...

    while (head != NULL) {
        head = free_node(head);
    }

    return 0;
}
```